# By which software/website this animated video was created?

Tags: video, animation

I'm looking for a software or online website that creates animated videos that supports the integration of a business logo.

[**Example - Facebook Video**](https://www.facebook.com/NeighborhoodLoans/videos/10154031509015734/)

I found many online services that create animated videos similar to this but with slightly lower quality. So I'd appreciate it if anyone could tell what is the name of the software or the website this page uses for creating their animated videos.

Comment: As we don't do "software identification" here, I hope you'd accept any software that matches your requirements. For that, we need some more details: what OS it must run on? Any price limit? For details what is expected, please see [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185)